# Ubuntu Raspberry Pi image source?

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi

Who created the `ubuntu-minimal-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz` image?

I found it linked from [here](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/), and it's the only Ubuntu 16.04 image I've found that works reliably on both the Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi 3, but it doesn't appear to be an official image released by Canonical. Unfortunately, the official Raspberry Pi images published by Canonical [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/release/) don't work on the Pi 3.

Comment: Martin Wimpress from  the [Ubuntu Pi Flavour Maker](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/) website is employed by Canonical as part of the Ubuntu Desktop Team.

Comment: Yes, but that site doesn't seem to host or make the images. They just host links to torrents. That image doesn't appear on  Canonical's official image servers.

Comment: https://lists.snapcraft.io/archives/snapcraft/2016-September/001166.html

Comment: @Mateo, What's that in reference to? That doesn't seem to mention this image...

Comment: it is the new official pi3 image, what then is the purpose of your question, to find the new pi images, or just the creator of the image you mentioned?

Comment: Canonical has released an official [Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi 3](http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz). The official instructions for installing it are at [Raspberry Pi | Ubuntu developer portal](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Canonical is now officially supporting Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS and 19.10 on raspberry-pi 2,3 (32 bit and 64 bit) and 4 (32 bit and 64 bit). You can find the downloads available here:

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi